# Large svn external

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have a project which uses a large library residing in its own repository.

Using: TortoiseSVN, the server is running an enterprise edition of VisualSVN

The project itself has the "standard" structure:

- trunk
- tags
- branches

In each branch, tag, and trunk is the library, set as an external (svn:external property). If I get the entire tree, I get the library several times, which is just getting too ridiculously repetitive.

Is there a recommended structure for this? Or perhaps a way not to get all externals (because other externals are much smaller, easier to manipulate)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The TortoiseSVN help has an appendix on [including a common subproject](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-howto-common-projects.html). If the library isn't likely to change, I think using a relative location (the third option listed) is probably the best.